# Logs for hive query executed via. beeline

Tags: hive, beeline

i am running below hive coomand from beeline  . Can someone please tell where can I see Map reudce logs for this ?

```
0: jdbc:hive2://<servername>:10003/> select a.offr_id offerID , a.offr_nm  offerNm  , b.disp_strt_ts  dispStartDt , b.disp_end_ts dispEndDt , vld_strt_ts validStartDt, vld_end_ts validEndDt from gcor_offr a, gcor_offr_dur b where a.offr_id = b.offr_id and b.disp_end_ts > '2016-09-13 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 3):

When using beeline, MapReduce logs are part of HiveServer2 log4j logs.

**If your Hive install was configured by Cloudera Manager (CM)**, then it will typically be in `/var/log/hive/hadoop-cmf-HIVE-1-HIVESERVER2-*.out` on the node where HiveServer2 is running (may or may not be the same as where you are running beeline from)

Few other scenarios:

- **Your Hive install was not configured by CM ?** You will need to manually create log4j config file:

  - Create `hive-log4j.properties` config file in directory specified by `HIVE_CONF_DIR` environment variable. (This makes it accessible to HiveServer2 JVM classpath)

    - In this file, log location is specified by `log.dir` and `log.file`. See `conf/hive-log4j.properties.template` in your distribution for an example template for this file.
- **You run beeline in "embedded HS2 mode"** (i.e. `beeline -u jdbc:hive2:// user password`) ?:

  - You will customize beeline log4j (as opposed to HiveServer2 log4j).
  - Beeline log4j properties file is strictly called `beeline-log4j2.properties` (in versions prior to Hive 2.0, it is called `beeline-log4j.properties`). Needs to be created and made accessible to beeline JVM classpath via `HIVE_CONF_DIR`. See HIVE-10502 and HIVE-12020 for further discussion on this.
- **You want to customize what HiveServer2 logs get printed on beeline stdout ?**

  - This can be configured at HiveServer2 level using `hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled` and `hive.server2.logging.operation` configs.

Answer (score 1):

Hive uses log4j for logging. These logs are not emitted to the standard output by default but are instead captured to a log file specified by Hive's log4j properties file. By default, Hive will use hive-log4j.default in the `conf/ directory` of the Hive installation which writes out logs to `/tmp/<userid>/hive.log` and uses the WARN level.

It is often desirable to emit the logs to the standard output and/or change the logging level for debugging purposes. These can be done from the command line as follows:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Comment: I strated beeline as below                                                                   beeline --verbose=true --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console    but still      logs are not coming

Answer (score 0):

```
set hive.async.log.enabled=false
```

Comment: This is not answer. The question was: where is the logfile ?